# executing emacs -batch on MS-DOS

Tags: emacs, elisp

does anyone know how to run something like the following on a Windows machine with the DOS command line?

```
emacs -batch -l functions.el --eval '(run-function "argument")'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This mostly works with official binaries for 23.1, but there are some quirks with command-line argument parsing.  Unlike `sh` or friends, `CMD.EXE` doesn't do much in the way of command-line parsing, so this is left to the application on windows.

Emacs.exe doesn't like single quotes:

```
C:\emacs-23.1\bin>emacs -batch --eval '(message "Foo!")'
End of file during parsing
```

Unsurprisingly, it doesn't like quotes embedded in the command either:

```
C:\emacs-23.1\bin>.\emacs -batch --eval "(message "Foo!")"
Symbol's value as variable is void: Foo!
```

Fortunately escaping with '\' seems to work OK:

```
C:\emacs-23.1\bin>.\emacs -batch --eval "(message \"Foo!\")"
Foo!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can't wait to try (I only have access to this machine at certain times a day which is why I want to leave an emacs-lisp code running in batch mode...)